# subset a list within a list by column's name start with all requested pattern

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames (L) with different column's name. I want to have a subset of a list which contains all requested columns name start with A and B (the sequence of A and B is not important.

```
L1 = data.frame(A1 = c(1:4) , Ab = c("u","v","w","x"))
L2 = data.frame(A2 = c(1:4) , Bc = c("u","v","w","x"))
L3 = data.frame(A3 = c(1:4) , Bd = c("u","v","w","x"))
L4 = data.frame(A = c(1:4) , B = c("u","v","w","x"))
L<-list(L1,L2, L3, L4)
```

The result should be a list with L2, L3, and L4 which contains columns start with A and B.

#######
Following command gives all lists which contain columns start with A or B but not subset a list which just start with both A and B.

```
lapply(L, function(x)   x[ , grepl( '^A|^B' , names(x))])
```

#######
and this function gives lists with exact requested columns name and not the columns start with A and B.

```
trial <- function(x) 
{
  reqnames <- c('A', 'B')
  L <- lapply(L, function(x)   all(reqnames  %in% names(x)))
  L <- which(L==1)
  x[L]
}
 trial(L)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all lists which contain columns start with A or B"? `L` is a list of lists. Each nested list, e.g. `L1`, is a list of named matrices with unnamed columns. Do you want to subset all matrices where the names start with `A` or `B`? If so why is `L1` not included as it has `A1`?

Comment: L1 does not have any columns which start with B. I want to have a subset of list which columns start with A AND B.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Firstly I assume by "columns" you mean the names of the matrices? Secondly, so you want to return all lists which have matrices with names starting with A **and** B?

Comment: I have edited the question as it was a bit confusing. Thanks @SamR your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
new_list  <- lapply(L, \(x) x[
    all(
        any(grepl("^A", names(x))),
        any(grepl("^B", names(x)))
    )
]
)
```

This will return an empty list in place of `L1`, and the contents of `L2` to `L4`.

If you don't want an empty list for `L1` you can subset it again:

```r
new_list[sapply(new_list, length)>0]
```